# Vuejs : Error while mapping values of chart - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'am using vue-apexharts to render chart, chart data comes from an api.

```
              this.statistics = response.data;
              this.statistics.consent.map((consent) => {
                this.series.push(consent.count);
              });
```

But an error is shown - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: This suggests that `response.data.consent` does not exist. Without seeing the response format it is difficult to say more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow when the map() function want to be executed, the `this.statistics.consent` is empty/null/undefined. try to debug it by `console.log(this.statistics.consent)`. Hope that helps and good luck!